# Submitting sonar-runner jobs to SonarQube with SSO via reverse proxy

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Our organization has SSO authentication via an Apache reverse proxy, which is currently working flawlessly.  I was surprised how easy it was to configure!

Now that I have this set up, however, I find that I am not able to submit jobs using sonar-runner.  When I look at the logs, I see that every access is redirected to the Federated SSO login page.

Is there some additional configuration that needs to be done to allow scans to go through without being authenticated?  Or perhaps some configuration options that need to be passed to the sonar-runner itself?

EDIT: We did consider a couple of options.

First, we thought about allowing only the URLs necessary to submit jobs to pass through the reverse proxy without authentication.  This is a tedious process at best and allows a path of entry into the service itself without authentication.

Second, we thought about passing a user token along with the request. There are two issues with this approach.  First, the existing URL is set up to authenticate using a three-legged approach.  As far as I know, I can't set up both two-legged and three-legged authentication for the same URL.  Second, we are submitting jobs using the Sonarqube plugin in Jenkins. Without modifying the plugin itself, there is no way to get a user token to pass through to the submit request.

Our workaround for the moment:  Since both systems are running in Docker containers, we submit from Jenkins by passing it to the IP address of the Sonarqube container.  This has the undesired effect of formatting the Sonarqube report links with a 172.17.0.x address rather than the FQDN.

Comment: Have you considered exempting SonarQube from your reverse proxy?

Comment: We did consider that and another option.  I've updated the original post to reflect our issues.